# Nothing happens after backup job created

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to backup a database in pgadmin4. Once the backup job is created nothing happens after and the file which is created is 0 bytes in size. Have you any idea about what's going wrong?

This is how I backup the database from pgadmin4

[image]

I'm running postgreSQL 9.6 on a macOS.

Comment: Check if there is a `pg_dump` process running on the machine.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe How to check that?

Comment: You should find somebody who knows how to administrate the operating system that pgAdmin is running on (you didn't tell us what that is, and you didn't give us any details anyway).